# Select a folder if images size is less than 1mb android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-bitmap

I am opening a folder onClick and sending images thro FTP. But when the size of image is more than 2MB i face an error in transmission. So I want open the folder if it has images with size less than 1MB else it will toast a message to check. Is this scenario possible as am new to android please help me.

```
protected void LoadGalleryImages() {
 final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
            String foldername=sharedpre.getString("FolderName", "");

            imagecursor=managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                    new String[] {"%/"+foldername+"/%"},null);          

            int image_column_index = 0;

            if (imagecursor != null) {
                image_column_index = imagecursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                count = imagecursor.getCount();
            }

            imgSelected = new String[count];

            arrPath = new String[count];
            thumbnailsselection = new boolean[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (imagecursor != null) {
                    imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);                  
                    int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                    arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use **MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE** in your managequery and filter it for particular size, so can get only those images which you required according to your requirement..

**EDIT :**

```
protected void LoadGalleryImages() {
 final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
            String foldername=sharedpre.getString("FolderName", "");

            imagecursor=managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                    new String[] {"%/"+foldername+"/%"},null);          

            int image_column_index = 0;

            if (imagecursor != null) {
                         String[] sizecolumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE };
                         Cursor imgcursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, sizecolumns,MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE + " < ? ",  new String[] {"1024"},null);

                if(imgcursor !=null) {
                         // Your Code
                }
            }

            imgSelected = new String[count];

            arrPath = new String[count];
            thumbnailsselection = new boolean[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (imagecursor != null) {
                    imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);                  
                    int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                    arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
                }
```

Comment: I dont get any error its opening all the images in specified folder not checking for the 1mb

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43661/discussion-between-pooja-and-segi)

Answer (score 1):

With

```
File [] files = %FOLDER%.listFiles();
```

you get the files of a directory. %FOLDER% is your directory you want to check. Just iterate over these files and return false if one of them is bigger than one MB.

```
if(files.length > 1048576){
    return false;
}
```

Put it in a method, pass the folder as argument and that is it.